# Magento admin not loading at all

Tags: admin, error, log

I've been dealing with a problem all morning where my website is working just fine but I can't access the admin panel. It's not that I can't log in, I can't even load the admin login screen. It was working perfectly yesterday.

The resulting page when accessing the admin is a completely blank page with no HTML, just a basic response header.

To make matters worse, I'm not being able to make the Magento log work, not even through

> Mage::log("something to log")

when it's placed in Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch.

PHP(apache) not throwing any errors either. Log files do work for apache.

I'm really out of ideas for this one. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a directory in you magento's root with the same name as your backend's directory e.g. admin.

Have you trying acessing mysite.com/index.php/admin ?

Comment: http status code is 200 or 500?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. There is no admin folder in root dir, and I get 404 when I try accessing mysite.com/admin as expected.
Code when trying to access admin is 200

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Not sure how it happened but my adminhtml directories from app/design/ and skin/ had been mysteriously deleted. I brought the dirs from another Magento install and everything is working fine now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great you found solution, but how was your directories deleted? I doubt it has been compromised unless you did yourself. I would suggest to check all thoroughly.